# How do I sort the values in a column in Impala SQL?

Tags: sql, impala

Is there a way that I can order the values in a column?

Sample Table 1

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | a,c,d,b |
| Cell 2 | b,a,c,d |

Expected Output

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | a,b,c,d |
| Cell 2 | a,b,c,d |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is column B values are array ? or just comma separated string ? In either case its going to be difficult to sort them. you can sort by elements but you need to clarify above question

Comment: Just comma separated string